# Java Socket/TCP and /dev/urandom

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I want to send some data using TCP Socket;
keyboard input is ok.
redirecting binary files fine too.
but
when I redirect /dev/urandom to stdin (java prog < /dev/urandom) nothing happens, no errors, no data send.

```
public class P1{
    static DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    int     port = 12345;
    String  host = "127.0.0.1";
    Socket p1Socket;
    DataOutputStream out;
    byte data;
    void run() {
        try{
            p1Socket = new Socket( host, port );
            out = new DataOutputStream(p1Socket.getOutputStream());

            while (dis.available() >0){
                data = dis.readByte();
                out.write   ( data        );

            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            p1Socket.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        P1 p1 = new P1();
        while (dis.available() <=0);
        p1.run();

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it surprising that you never finish preparing to send an infinite amount of data?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `available` method, it only tells you if something can be read without blocking, which is pretty useless. Use an infinite loop instead.

```
        while (true) {
            data = dis.readByte();
            out.write(data);
        }
```

End-of-file is signaled with `EOFException`. Make sure that you close the file when exceptions are thrown.

Comment: There's a second place in your program where you have a loop around `available`. Did you remove it?